# Прорисовка карты с маршрутом

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отключить прорисовку маршрута до полной его готовности. То есть показать карту только когда весь весь маршрут будет сформирован.

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function init() {
            var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
                referencePoints: [
                    [53.7472301068544, 87.1177096741265],
[53.7535593053719, 87.1182865722019],
[53.757066429694, 87.1184041616726],
[53.7611378129068, 87.1185043238268],
[53.7633949909674, 87.1150907257471],
[53.7651320504216, 87.1036804148398],
[53.7710005056744, 87.1016787887237],
[53.7667860645947, 87.0942806233698],
[53.7566611540789, 87.0885903350341],
[53.7530959647668, 87.0847338675193],
[53.7506425644254, 87.0743838381418],
[53.7513875815114, 87.0618752469681],
[53.7515762695034, 87.0526045434045],
[53.747720082387, 87.040476119259],
[53.7448029873482, 87.0328971230384],
[53.7457869832064, 87.0192332085778],
[53.7485576919019, 87.0130138125397],
[53.7527330829135, 87.0053422000133]                
                ]
            }, {

                wayPointVisible: false,
                boundsAutoApply: true
            });

            var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
                center: [53.7472301068544, 87.1177096741265],
                zoom: 15
            });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);

            myCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, {
                preset: 'islands#grayStretchyIcon'
            });

            myCollection
                .add( new ymaps.GeoObject({ geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [53.7472301068544, 87.1177096741265]},
                    properties: { iconContent: 'Вокзал' }
                    }))
                    .add( new ymaps.GeoObject({ geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [53.7527330829135, 87.0053422000133]},
                    properties: { iconContent: 'АЗС' }
                }))
                ;

            myMap.geoObjects.add(myCollection);


        }

        ymaps.ready(init);
    </script>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 720px; padding-bottom:15px">
```

Cтраница с маршрутом здесь:
https://www.vokzal-nk.ru/bus-53

Answer (score 0):

Можно прятать карту при старте, дожидаться события "activeroutechange" на экземпляре маршрута и показывать карту

https://jsfiddle.net/gqx54o1L/19/

```
multiRoute.events.add('activeroutechange', function () {
    document.getElementById('map').classList.remove('hidden');
});
```